# Possible pattern to center buttons

Tags: html, css

i am creating a homepage, for this i have placed a navigation bar on top of the viewport. The navigation bar contains buttons which should, attention, navigate the user from one section to another.
But actually they are placed on the left. I want them to be exactly center no matter if there are 2,3,4 or 5+ buttons. The whole "button-line" should exactly be centered.

Or to talk in pictures:

[image]

What is a common/possible pattern to accomplish this?

The only pattern i have in mind is to add a width to the button `home` and `ubuntu` and finally add `margin 0 auto`.

**My navigationbar.css(the purple bar):**

```
#navigationBar {

    background-color:#660099;

    }

.navigationButton {

    background-color:transparent;
    border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;

    }

.navigationButton:hover {

    background-color:transparent;
    border-bottom:2px solid #18ab29;
    }

.navigationButton:active {

    position:relative;
    top:1px;

    }
```

**my home.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Ubuntu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/general.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/navigationBar.css" />
 </head>

 <body>
   <div id="navigationBar">
     <a href="home.html" class="navigationButton">Home</a>
     <a href="ubuntuOverview.html" class="navigationButton">Ubuntu</a>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope somebody can help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this:-

```
#navigationBar {
    background-color:#660099;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, it is working well! But why can i treat an anchor <a ... /> as a text? Does it center every elements like inner divs as well. A little explanation would be nice..

Comment: Yes this concept will work with all elements. But aslo check that is `inline` or block elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 flexbox specification, which is designed specifically for this purpose. Basically, all you need is to set the parent container to `display: flex`, and justify its content centrally, i.e. `justify-content: center`.

```css
#navigationBar {
  background-color: #660099;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.navigationButton {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 16px 31px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
.navigationButton:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #18ab29;
}
.navigationButton:active {
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigationBar">
  <a href="home.html" class="navigationButton">Home</a>
  <a href="ubuntuOverview.html" class="navigationButton">Ubuntu</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answere. I am interested in this kind of solution.. is there any advantage over Maddys solution?

Comment: The only issue with inline-block elements is the whitespace between them if they are entered on a new line in HTML, as per inline elements, any whitespace will be collapsed into a single whitespace and treated as such. Flexbox also allow for easy handling of a few layout variations :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.navigationParent{
text-align:center;
}
.navigationBar{
display:inline-block;
}
```

If the bar dispaly is set to inline-block then textalin:center will work for it:

```
<div class="navigationParent">
     <div class="navigationBar">
          <a href="home.html" class="navigationButton">Home</a>
          <a href="ubuntuOverview.html" class="navigationButton">Ubuntu</a>      
    </div>
</div>
```